# AngularJS $apply inside scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there another approach which could be used to carry out the following?  This jQuery function is used inside the Angular $scope, and it works fine however it throws an $apply error, essentially because it's seen as an $apply inside an $apply. Yet if I remove $scope.$apply() line it stops working.

```
function myfunction(start, end) {
        // Lots of jQuery code here - omitted from this example

        // Update the scope 
        $scope.myf = "abc";
        $scope.myt = "def";
        $scope.$apply();
}

myfunction();
```

Comment: _"it works fine however it throws an $apply error" - It cannot be both working and not working.

Comment: The output desired, is produced yet it throws an error. Perhaps I should re-word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$scope.$evalAsync()` instead. it would not throw an error and do the same in this case.

Comment: Thank you.  Because the function was not tied to a jQuery event - this solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Either wrap your code in a $timeout or use $apply(). Note that $timeout is calling  $apply() internally. $apply is specially made to resync external changes (not in angular loop) with angular.

If your function trigger on click or on event. You can bind your function to angular by using the directive ng-click or ng-[event].